# Is $p^{-s}$ transcendental if $\zeta(s)=0$?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, riemann-zeta-function, zeta-functions

Let $K$ be a number field and $\mathcal{O}_{K}$ its ring of integers.

Let

$$\zeta_{K}(s)=\prod_{\mathfrak{m}}\frac{1}{1-\#(\mathcal{O}_{K}/\mathfrak{m})^{-s}}$$
be the $\zeta$ function associated to $K$.

Let $p$ be a prime and $s$ a zero of $\zeta_{K}$ with $\operatorname{Re}(s)>0$.

**Question**: Is $p^{-s}$ transcendental?

This would of course be true $s$ were algebraic, as a consequence of the Gelfond–Schneider theorem.

I believe that all such zeros are at least conjectured to be transcendental.

Comment: Is there an intuition that suggests that it should be?

Comment: This was cross-posted from MSE, please indicate as such: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4597199/is-ps-transcendental-if-zetas-0#comment9682618_4597199

Comment: It is a standard conjecture that every zero of every primitive L-function (except for zeros at the critical point), has transcendental imaginary part and is algebraically independent of every other zero of every other L-function, and also algebraically independent of every other reasonable number you can imagine.  And it is also believed there is no hope of proving anything like that.  So, yes, the number in your question is expected to be transcendental, but there is no hope of proving it.  (Also, it is standard to use $\rho$ for a zero of the zeta function, and $s$ for a complex variable.)

Comment: A "primitive" L-function does not factor as a product of L-functions.  The Dedekind zeta function of a number field is never primitive.  So the question is really about the primitive factors of that Dedekind zeta function